# How to do Matrix Multiplication in OpenGL 4.3?

Tags: opengl, 3d

Are the functions like `glmatrixmode()`, `gltranslate()`, `glrotate()`, and `glscale()` deprecated in OpenGL 4.3?

If they are deprecated, what are the new functions in Core OpenGL  profile that do matrix manipulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're all deprecated.

You're supposed to manage your matrices locally outside of OpenGL, then upload them as uniform variables with [`glUniformMatrix*`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml)

Answer (score 6):

They are not deprecated. They are *removed*. There's a difference.

Deprecated means "available, but may be removed later." Removed means "not available."

You should use a vector/matrix library. Either one you write or [one someone else wrote](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Related_toolkits_and_APIs#Math_Libraries).

Comment: Something that has been removed is sometimes called deprec_i_ated (what a large difference changing a single letter can have). Literally this means, something that has been deprecated and now has been consequently been removed.

Comment: @datenwolf: I don't see that [in the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/depreciated?db=*). Or [this one.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/depreciate).

Comment: thank you, i got the point so i should do everything with GLSL